# Binding combobox - WPF & C#

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have read loads of posts about this topic, but I cannot for the life of me figure this out, so your help is appreciated as I am losing the will to live!

I am trying to bind a list to a combobox in WPF, here is my code:

ViewModel:

```
 public class ViewModelAddRegion
  {    
    public List<DataAccessLayer.Model.CountryList> CountryList { get; set; }

    public object GetCountryList()
    {
        List<DataAccessLayer.Model.CountryList> CountryList = new List<DataAccessLayer.Model.CountryList>();
        CountryList = Data.DatabaseGets.GetAllCountries();
        return CountryList;
    }
}
```

So that gets my list. In the backing to my window, the code is:

```
public AddRegion()
    {
        var vm = new WineDatabase.ViewModel.ViewModelAddRegion();      
        var CountryAllList = vm.GetCountryList();
        DataContext = CountryAllList;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

And finally, in my window:

```
<ComboBox Name="CountryList"
                  Margin="159,0,-160,0" 
                  Grid.Row="1" 
                  Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding CountryAllList}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="CountryName"/>
```

Debugging, my list is populated as expected, but the combobox is forever empty.

Thanks for any assistance at all!

Comment: One thing I've noticed when binding lists with WPF, is that its almost better to use an ObservableCollection instead. At least if you know the data will change and want the changes to reflect easily. If the data never changes then a List should work fine. That being said, it looks like your setting the DataContext to the List and not to the ViewModel itself.

Answer (score 1):

`CountryAllList` is just a local variable that you can't bind to. See the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN for details.

You should assign the ViewModel instance to the DataContext

```
var vm = new WineDatabase.ViewModel.ViewModelAddRegion();
vm.CountryList = vm.GetCountryList();
DataContext = vm;
```

and bind to its `CountryList` property

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CountryList}" ... />
```

Finally, in your `GetCountryList` method, it doesn't make much sense to assign the return value of `Data.DatabaseGets.GetAllCountries()` to a local variable. You could instead directly return it from the method.

```
public List<DataAccessLayer.Model.CountryList> GetCountryList()
{
    return Data.DatabaseGets.GetAllCountries();
}
```

---

The `GetCountryList()` method may as well directly assign to the `CountryList` property

```
public void GetCountryList()
{
    CountryList = Data.DatabaseGets.GetAllCountries();
}
```

and you could write the initialization code like this:

```
var vm = new WineDatabase.ViewModel.ViewModelAddRegion();
vm.GetCountryList();
DataContext = vm;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, and the advice. Amended the code as you suggested and the combobox is still blank. Do I need to set the CountryList property anywhere else outside of the method that returns it?

Answer (score 1):

Change `AddRegion` method to:

```
public AddRegion()
{
    var vm = new WineDatabase.ViewModel.ViewModelAddRegion();      
    vm.CountryList = vm.GetCountryList();
    DataContext = vm;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

And in ComboBox set `ItemsSource="{Binding CountryList}"`

Comment: Used the first version and it works, I get the list. Thanks to the both of you.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to set vm.CountryList in AddRegion as it is already set in GetCountryList() (which could be changed to something like LoadCountryList and not return value, for clarity).

Comment: @Shadowed CountryList in OP's original method is a local variable, so the property isn't set there. That's why I edited your post.

Comment: I see. He created local variable of the same name as property.